# Confundido con NSURLSession delegate

Tags: swift2, swift

```
class ImageTrack {

    var session: NSURLSession?
    var delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?
    var task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

    func update() {
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: delegate!, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())
    }

    func searchImage() {
        if task != nil {
            task?.cancel()
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Screen-Shot-2015-08-20-at-12.27.21-am.png")!
        task = session!.downloadTaskWithURL(url)

        task?.resume()
    }

}
```

No entiendo como es posible que si el init de `NSURLSession` me pide un delegate del tipo `NSURLSessionDelegate` pueda llamar a los métodos de un protocolo hijo como sería con `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` con el método:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL).
```

***EDIT***
Mi pregunta trata sobre la variable delegate del NSURLSession que es de tipo NSURLSESSIONDELEGATE y que no es un NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate(aunque sí al revés), por lo que a menos que se haga un cast(del delegate) no puede llamar a los métodos de NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate. 
Por lo que mi pregunta es: ¿Internamente en el código se hace un cast?

Comment: Puedes aclarar tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

No me queda del todo claro quién es `delegate` en el código de la pregunta...

De todas formas, si el constructor espera un objeto de tipo `NSURLSessionDelegate`, puedes pasarle un objeto que implemente `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` ya que hay herencia de protocolos...

Me imagino que el código quedaría algo así:

```
public class ImageTrack: NSObject, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    var session: NSURLSession?
    var task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

    func update() {
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())
    }

    public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())`. Mi problema está en esta línea, como es posible que la session llame a un método de `NSURLSsessionDownloadDelegate` si está guardado como un `NSURLSessionDelegate`.  Se me ocurre un cast dentro de la session pero no creo que suceda eso.

Comment: Eso es simplemente porque cualquier objeto que implemente el protocolo `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`, **obligatoriamente** debe implementar también el protocolo `NSURLSessionDelegate`.

Comment: Perdón no me estoy dando a entender uh. Lo que decis lo entiendo y lo sé, pero la variable delegate del `NSURLSession` es de tipo `NSURLSESSIONDELEGATE`, que no es un `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`(aunque sí al revés) por lo que a menos que se haga un cast(del delegate) no puede llamar a los métodos de `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`.

Comment: Es correcto, deberías hacer un cast. `if let downloadDelegate = delegate as? NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {...`

Comment: Así es como lo maneje internamente la session, correcto?